# What happened in rasterizer stage?

Tags: graphics, direct3d, direct3d11

I want to use Direct3D 11 to blend several images that from multi-view into one texture, so i do multiple projection at Vertex Shader stage and Geometry Shader stage, one of the projection's result stored in SV_Position, others stored in POSITION0, POSITION1 and so on. These positions would be used to sample the image.

Then at the Pixel shader stage, the value in SV_Position is typical like a (307.5,87.5), because it's in screen space. as the size of render target is 500x500, so the uv for sample is (0.615,0.0.175), it's correct. but value in POSITION0 would be like a (0.1312, 0.370), it's vertical reversed with offset. i have to do (0.5 + x, 0.5 - y). the projection is twisted and just roughly matched.

What do the rasterizer stage do on SV_Position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rasterizer stage expects the coordinates in `SV_Position` to be *normalized device coordinates*. In this space X and Y values between `-1.0` and `+1.0` cover the whole output target, with Y going "up". That way you do not have to care about the exact output resolution in the shaders.

So as you realized, before a pixel is written to the target another transformation is performed. One that inverts the Y axis, scales X and Y and moves the origin to the top left corner.

In Direct3D11 the parameters for this transformation can be controlled through the [`ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetViewports`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476480.aspx) method.

If you need pixel coordinates in the pixel shader you have to do the transformation yourself. For accessing the output resolution in the shader bind them as shader-constants, for example.

Comment: So, did the coordinate after projection transform to be a NDC? What viewpoints transform seems to be just  like what `(0.5 + x, 0.5 - y)` do

Comment: projected position divided with its w, then become NDC, and it worked, Thx!

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to mention that `SV_Position` can in fact be outside of the `[-1, 1]` range before the perspective divide.